# How to reschedule 403 response pages with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

Once in a while I am getting a 403 response while scraping pages with Scrapy 2.4.1. The downloadmiddleware is set to 5 tries and it does give up after the 5th try:

```
2021-02-06 01:44:17 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.url...> (failed 5 times): 403 Forbidden
2021-02-06 01:44:17 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www.url...>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

The documentation however tells me that failed pages will be rescheduled at the end of the crawl, which is not the case. Once Scrapy gives up on that page it does not retry again.

> Failed pages are collected on the scraping process and rescheduled at
> the end, once the spider has finished crawling all regular (non
> failed) pages.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/retry.html

My question is: How can I configure the middleware that it does not instantly retry those pages once they fail, but continues with another URL and reschedules them after the rest of the pages have been crawled?

Comment: Scrapy should do that by default: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std-setting-RETRY_PRIORITY_ADJUST . On the other hand, if all your requests come from `start_urls`/`start_requests`, those are *not* even added to the scheduler until it’s running out of requests, so retries can always happen before those requests.

Comment: I believe this is where the problem lies. I add each URL I want to scrape to start_urls list and limit the  crawl to that list. The goal is to crawl a given list of URLs. Is there another way where I can utilize the scheduler for this use case?

Comment: Until Scrapy supports feeding all URLs into the scheduler (which will probably happen, but it will take time), a possible hack would be to have a single, fake start URL, e.g. to `file:///dev/null` in Linux, and use its callback (e.g. `parse`) to yield the actual start requests. I think that way they are added to the scheduler. I’m not 100% sure, but please let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid 403 error, I use a different user agent, like this:

```
    import random
    def get_header():
    headers_list = [
    # Firefox 77 Mac
     {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Referer": "https://www.google.com/",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
    },
    # Firefox 77 Windows
    {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Referer": "https://www.google.com/",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
    },
    # Chrome 83 Mac
    {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Referer": "https://www.google.com/",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
    },
    # Chrome 83 Windows
    {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Referer": "https://www.google.com/",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
    }
]

    return random.choice(headers_list)
```

Then, in your main function, just call it like this:

```
header = get_header()
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
```

For me, this avoids the 403 error most of the time.

Comment: Weil I rotate the agent on every request. Out of 10000 req I do get about a 100 403 errors. The question was how to reschedule those.

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt understand that like this. Maybe you can test if the test the request response status code and if it’s 403, you try the same request?